# Activiti Timer dynamic expression

Tags: activiti

We are using activiti for workflow. In one of the flow between one step to another we have wait timer as shown below

```
<sequenceFlow id="sequence_my_flow_successful_signal_3" sourceRef="my_flow_gateway" targetRef="signal_my_flow_successful_3"/>
    <intermediateCatchEvent id="timer_my_flow_3">
      <timerEventDefinition>
        <timeDuration>PT48H</timeDuration>
      </timerEventDefinition>
    </intermediateCatchEvent>
```

Is it possible to have an expression which dynamically returns timeDuration (Internally call java code with business key) and have the timerDuration return value based on some condition

I know I could add expression something like below for serviceTask where I could call java code

```
<serviceTask id="service_my_flow_lead" activiti:exclusive="true" name="Handle My Flow Lean" activiti:expression="${myFlowDelegate.createMyFlowLead(execution.parent.businessKey)}"/>
```

Thank you